# Is there any valid reason to have a blank/empty .rb file in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My team recently encountered an issue where we deleted all contents of a `.rb` file located in the `models` directory in a Rails project, leaving it completely blank/empty -- but inadvertently did not delete the file itself.

This later resulted in an the error of the form `LoadError: Unable to autoload constant MyFileName, expected /my_project/app/models/my_file_name.rb to define it`, due to the Rails autoloader expecting that file to define a class of the corresponding name. (Of course, there was no such class defined, because the file was blank).

My question: Is there ever a good reason for a blank `.rb` file to be present in a Rails project -- either in the `models` folder, or anywhere else?

We're considering implementing some form of automated check to help prevent this same problem from occurring in the future. Before doing that, I want to understand whether or not there are any valid reasons for blank `.rb` files to be present in a Rails project.

Comment: There isn't a good reason to have an empty .rb file just as there isn't a good reason to waste company resources writing an app that detects them.  Wait to write the app when the second occurrence happens (probably never)

Comment: If there truly is no valid reason to ever have a blank/empty .rb file in a Rails project, I'm considering submitting a PR to Rubocop to to add a new (optional?) rule to detect such a condition -- which would potentially help many teams working with Rails apps (not just mine).

Comment: Here's the aforementioned Rubocop pull request: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/7780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an empty ruby file does nothing.

Seems like a weird oversight that shouldn't happen too often. If there is no table corresponding with that model anymore just delete the file. If there is still a table, was the file contents deleted accidentally? Do you need to revert those changes?

Comment: The intended change in my team's recent case that lead to this post was a rename of a database table and its associated Rails model class. It was an error (which was not  caught by our existing tooling, e.g. Rubocop) that the file for the old-name copy of the model class was merely blanked out instead of being deleted entirely.

Comment: makes sense. a cut and paste to a new file. They should have just refactored the filename and class of the existing file though ;)